# Import External part of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it valid to import part of published HTML file to a DIV inside my local HTML file using Jquery?!
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".import-to" ).load( "https://souqcms.s3.amazonaws.com/spring/cms/en/eg/2015/LPs/Test/Arabic_Fonts/index.html h1" );
    })
</script>

<div class="import-to"></div>
```

Comment: valid to the point of implementing a html5 import function directly into html :))

Comment: But I don't want to use the HTML5 import function

Comment: the script above is valid

Comment: if you do a load of a local page is valid, what you are doing now is a loading a page from external source that is why is not working the external source is blocking you

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try to find another way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cross-domain issue using Ajax. You must be sure you are accessing your files on the same http:// path without www. (or access from http://www. and post to the same path including www.) which the browser considers as another domain when accessing via a www. path, so you see where the problem is. You are posting to a different domain and the browser blocks the flow because of the origin issue.

If the API is not placed on the same host that you are requesting from, the flow is blocked, and you will need to find another way to communicate with the API.